# Hide Seconds, millisec timezone from datetimepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I am using http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ example to include datetimepicker in my jsp page.

I am able to plug everything and when click it pops up too.
Now the popup has Slider for Seconds, milli, micro and timezone which is surplus to my requirement. Can anyone pls help how to hide these sliders from the plugin.

I tried setting the property for all them to false like $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({showSeconds: false}); but this doesnt work.

Answer (score 4):

Forgot to add css file in jsp file. Added that in head and then used showSecond: false and it working now.

Comment: what .css file did you used?